# enable PHP in apache mac m1

Tags: php, macos, apache2, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I try to install php on a mac m1 working with apache,

```
brew install php
```

It looks fine in CLI

> php -version PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2022 04:34:05) (NTS)

So i try to load the module in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file like this :

```
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

I try different paths but although I can reload apache without problem, I can't access
an index.php page with php code in it, this is the only error messgae I ve got in error.log:

> [pid 80745] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue...

enter `apachectl configtest` on the terminal and you will get the error message :

```
No code signing authority for module at /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so specified in LoadModule directive.
httpd: Syntax error on line 190 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Code signing absent - not loading module at: /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

Comment: Thanks that s very helpful, I m going to look into that